# Send touch ended event to UIControl subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontrol

I have a class that extends `UIControl` and overrides `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` methods.

From another class, I want to have the `touchesEnded:withEvent:` getting called on an instance of my subclass.

This:

```
[myControl sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

doesn't cause neither one of the 2 methods to get called.

Comment: Did you call the super method when your overrides it?

Comment: No, you don't call the super of those methods.

Comment: Oops. I confused it with custom gesture recognizers.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to synthesise/generate a UITouch event (without a finger touching the screen) and then send it to your UIControl subclass as a parameter to `-touchesEnded:withEvent:`, then you can't.

   Apple does not allow us to generate these, only iOS is allowed to generate and distribute UITouch events along the Responder Chain. There are some undocumented ways to do it if you google "synthesize UITouch", but Apple is quite hostile to these and rejects apps that use them.
2. The code that you posted

   `[myControl sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

   only causes the action associated with the corresponding control event (TouchUpInside) to be triggered. It has no effect on touchesBegan/Moved/Ended. If you had an action `-handleTap` and target `viewController` assigned to your control, sending `-sendActionsForControlEvents;` would only cause following message to be sent

   `[viewController handleTap];`
3. If you want to intercept and redirect an actual touch event (that iOS for some reason does not send to your UIControl subclass), it would be easiest to do from any of your objects in the Reponder Chain - the visible UIView (and subclasses) hierarchy and "active" view controller(s), app delegate and UIApplication objects. Just override their own -touchesBegan/Moved/Ended methods and nest the call inside, but I'm sure you thought about that

`-touchesEnded:NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [myControl touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}`

4. Since you want to call methods on your own class, instead of overriding `-touchesBegan/Moved/Ended`, can't you just add some custom method to the UIControl subclass that does not require UITouch & UIEvent parameters and simply call it. For example

`-(void)touchAt:(CGPoint)location {
    //react to touch
}`

and call it from your other class

`[myControl touchAt:CGPointMake(2.5, 2.5)];`